# How can we get google map search result as json file?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create an app that list items, that get by search in google map.
Its only for display particular details about near hospital. I don't know how to convert map result into json object

I am beginner in android development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview) provides these web services as an interface for requesting Maps API data from external services and using them within your Maps applications.

These web services use `HTTP` requests to specific `URLs`, passing URL parameters as arguments to the services. Generally, these services return data in the HTTP request as either *JSON* or *XML* for parsing and/or processing by your application.

A typical web service request is generally of the following form:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/service/output?parameters
```

where service indicates the particular service requested and output indicates the response format `(usually json or xml)`.

[`JSON (Javascript Object Notation)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#ParsingJSON) has an obvious advantage over XML in that the response is lightweight. Parsing such a result is trivial in JavaScript as the format is already a valid Javascript object. For example, to extract the value of the 'formatted_address' keys within a JSON result object, simply access them using the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < myJSONResult.results.length; i++) {
myAddress[i] = myJSONResult.results[i].formatted_address;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to search places from google maps

```
String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
    "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
    "&radius=1000&sensor=true" +
    "&types=hospital"+
    "&key=your_key_here";
```